# Converting array of form data into json angularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have code as below, where I am trying to convert my form values into json object and trying to print the same in JSON format whenever submit button is clicked. I am able to print the form values but I am failing to print it in JSON format.

https://codepen.io/karthikeyan4142/pen/RjyPRo

code i tried to convert object to JSON is

```
angular.toJson($scope.editedArrayDetails)
JSON.stringify($scope.editedArrayDetails)
```

Expected format:

```
{
"Label 1"  : "Jr.High1",
"Label 2"  : "HighSchool",
"Label 3"  : "College",
"Label 4"  : "vds",
"Label 5"  : "svd"
}
```

I got the expected format conversion as per below code and it is working, but how to call an external and get response?

working:

https://codepen.io/karthikeyan4142/pen/YELXgx

I also want to call an external API with this JSON request and get the response back. how can that be done?

Comment: What you are getting IS json. Please specify the required format you are aiming for.

Comment: @dev8080 his "edited _array_" is an array and not JSON object, but the format is indeed not specified

Comment: I believe he wants an object, not an array, but arrays too are expressed in json...which is what he is getting.

Comment: I got the expected format as mentioned above.